# reading and writing file for a game

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream, turbo-c++

I am making a game with random initialized letters (ex. B A S T E N), and the user will type as many words possible using only those letters. I have a file which has the correct words with their corresponding points. My problem is how do I prevent the user from using the same words over and over?

I'm trying to use ofstream so that whenever a user inputs a correct word it will be added to blank file

```
void start()
{
    char ch;
    do {
        clrscr();
        long* newptr = 0;
        time_t start = time(newptr);
        char arr[10][50] = {" B A N S E T ", " R E D G A E ", " S A H L E S ", " P R G N I S ",
                            " A L E R L Y ", " L A C S A U ", " A C Q U K Y ", " M B L U E J ",
                            " Z E D Z U B ", " L E A Z D Z "};
        int i = 0, sum, x;
        while (i != 2) {
            clrscr();
            sum = 0;
            do {
                clrscr();
                cout << "\t**********************************************\n";
                cout << "\t*             W O R D  S E E K E R           *\n";
                cout << "\t**********************************************\n";
                cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\t SCORE: " << sum << " /50 pts"
                     << "\n                  ******************************\n";
                cout << "                  *       " << arr[i] << "        *\n";
                cout << "                  ******************************\n\n";
                cout << " 6 letter=10pts, 5 letter=8pts, 4 letters=6pts, 3 letter=4pts\n\n";
                char a[20], b[20];
                int c;

                // this is where I have my problem
                if (i == 0) {
                    ifstream fin;
                    fin.open("lvl1.txt");
                    if (fin.fail()) {
                        cout << "File doesn't exist!";
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    ofstream fout;
                    fout.open("trial.txt");
                    if (fout.fail()) {
                        cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
                    }
                    cout << "\tEnter word: ";
                    cin >> a;

                    do {
                        fout << a;
                        fin >> b >> c;
                        if (fin.eof() == 1) {
                            cout << "Incorrect! Try Again!";
                            delay(1000);
                            exit(1);
                        }
                    } while (strcmp(a, b) != 0);
                    fin.close();
                    if (strcmp(a, b) == 0) {
                        sum += c;
                    }
                }
            } while (sum < 50);
            i++;
        }
        x = time(newptr) - start;
        cout << "\n\tGood Job! Your time is " << x << " seconds\n";
        cout << "\tDo you want to continue?(Y/N): ";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch != 'n' || ch != 'N');
}
```

Comment: Please present your code in a readable format. I'm not going to read your chaotic code. One statement per line, proper indentation, and so on. There are even programs that do the formatting for you. Use them.

Comment: @RolandIllig I've edited the part where the ifstream and ofstream are, sorry if it's a mess.

Comment: I ran it through clang-format for you. If you're not using clang-format yourself, then you can (in the future) use an [online service](http://format.krzaq.cc/) for this.

Comment: @NikosC. thank you very much, sorry I'm still a noob when it comes to this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A question is whether you want to remember the words during run-time or after the program ends.

To remember words after the program ends, write them to a file.

To remember words the User has entered during run-time, use a *container*, such as `std::vector`.  Append the word to the container, then sort the container.  You can use `std::binary_search` to find the word in the container before you append.

Comment: Preferably the latter so I won't need to remove the words from file every time a new user tries to play. Also I forgot to tell you I'm only allowed to use turbo c++ it is for a project

Comment: Ask your instructor why you must use Turbo C++, a *very* old compiler, when you can download a modern free compiler for free (or use an online compiler for small projects).  The school really needs to change its curriculum.

Comment: A good match for the problem at hand would be `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: If you don't have `std::vector`, you will need to write it yourself.  Dynamically allocate an array of size N.  When the array is full, allocate a new, larger array; copy the old array to the new array, then delete the old array.

Comment: Another suggestion is to write your own linked list and use an Insertion Sort with the words.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews How do I create that? Sorry I'm still new to programming

Comment: I prefer to search the internet when I need to know how to do something.  You could use the keywords "c++ linked list insertion sort" or "c++ binary search array", "c++ sort array".  The instructions for creating a linked list already exist on StackOverflow and the internet; too lengthy to post in a comment; and not an answer to your post.